# Submitting PR on GitHub

Tags: github, pull-request

ALL,

I have a fork of some repository (wxWidgets).

In my fork on my home machine I made a branch, made some changes and pushed. Then grabbed them on another machine, made some changes and pushed.

At this point I went to the GitHub UI in the FF and I did see the button to submit the PR on both of those machines.

Today couple of minutes ago I came to work, opened the Chrome, logged in to GitHub and  navigated to the main repository of wxWidgets. However I don't see a button to submit the PR.

I switched to my fork and I do see the branch with all latest commits, but not on the main wxWidgets repository.

Why?

TIA!!